# How to commit from concourse pipeline?

Tags: continuous-integration, concourse

What is the best way to commit from a pipeline.The job pulls from a different repo and makes some changes + builds - then push the new files to a different repo.Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [git-resource](https://github.com/concourse/git-resource).

The basic steps of what you are going to want to do are to

- Pull from the repo into a container.
- Do some stuff with the code
- Move the new code into a different container
- Push the contents of that new container to a different git-repository

Your pipeline configuration should look something like this:

```
jobs:
- name: pull-code
  plan:
  - get: git-resource-pull
  - get: git-resource-push
  - task: do-something
    inputs: 
    - name: git-resource-pull
    run:
    path: /bin/bash
    args:
    - -c
    - |
      pushd git-resource-pull
        // do something
      popd
      // move the code from git-resource-pull to git-resource-push
  - put: git-resource-push
    params: {repository: git-resource-push}

resources:
- name: git-resource-pull
  type: git
  source:
    uri: https://github.com/team/repository-1.git
    branch: master

- name: git-resource-push
  type: git
  source:
    uri: https://github.com/team/repository-2.git
    branch: master
```